# ROOT: How to allow "install unknown apps" by default for an app?

Tags: adb, root-access, unknown-sources

Since Android 8.0 `adb shell settings put secure install_non_market_apps 1` no longer works because we now have to enable it for a specific app.

I am using Android 9.0 and I have root access on my device. Is there a way (using adb or other means) to allow my app to "install unknown apps" by default? I want my app to be able to update itself without opening settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using `appops`.

```
adb shell appops set <package name> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES allow
```

I haven't tested this for unrooted devices but it definitely works for my rooted device.